# Long timeout when trying to call WebGet call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httprequest, global-asax

We have a web app that as part of its actions it calls web api methods (with WebGet attribute).

Until now we didn`t have any special performance problems , but when we installed our server side that contains the web api calls, in new server (same settings as other servers),
we got very long time out and bad performance.

After adding some logs and using profiling to figure out where is the root of the problem,
we found out this:
In out `Global.asax` we have the regular events :

```
Application_BeginRequest, Application_AuthenticateRequest and Application_EndRequest.
```

We saw that there is a hole of a minute or more between the end of `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method and the arrival to our actual web api method.

We almost out of ideas..can you please help us with new directions of solving this problem?

Comment: With no ideia what can be happening i'd learn exactly what's the lifecycle in global.asax to understand what can be happening in between

Comment: I have tried adding the other events but there is still a gap between the last event before the call between the call itself.

The event before the call is : Application_PreSendRequestContent.

Hope someone can figure out what can it be.